# Vimeo embeds with Cycle2

Tags: jquery, plugins, embed, vimeo, jquery-cycle2

I'm using the Cycle2 jQuery plugin for creating a slideshow, and I would like to include Vimeo embeds if possible. There is an extension for YouTube embeds made by the author but there's nothing about Vimeo or how to make a workaround using the YouTube script. Anyone tried this before? Also greatly appreciating any suggestions on other plugins, if necessary, to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally used this plugin, but looks promising. Take a look at [Pretty Photo](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#prettyPhoto). Looks [simple to use](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation) and also supports a wide range of browsers

Firefox 3.0+ 
Google Chrome 10.0+ 
Internet Explorer 6.0+ 
Safari 3.1.1+ 
Opera 9+

How to init a [Slideshow](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#slideshow-image-gallery-overview) and how to use it with [Vimeo](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#vimeo-overview).

Do let me know if this helps.

-- Arvind.